# connect client to server and get a text file from it in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server, client, connect

I would like to connect automatically from a client to a server with an IP address in C# and get a text file from the server.

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: depending on what service you want to use in your server, ftp, http, ...?

Comment: @mcNets i have a server with windows server

Comment: to get something from your server you need some app/service, if you install a ftp server you can connect with a ftp client, if you use IIS you can use http to make calls, or even you can write your app server. The best? it depends

Comment: @mcNets my program is windows c# form base and i need to get a file from server

Comment: you can share a folder in your server but it's really insecure to publish your  files in internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## WebClient

The simplest way to do so is using "WebClient". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

This class has a function called

```
public string DownloadString(string address)
```

You can use this to download the text file to memory.
For more Methods (e.g. DownloadFile) visit the given link. Note: This Method might hang the window if executed in the UI-Thread while downloading the content. Either use a second Thread to do the stuff or use the asynchronous methods if possible.

In this case you would rather use this:

```
public Task<string> DownloadStringTaskAsync(string address)
```

More Information about Async: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to achieve using a WebRequest as follows.

```
// Create a request for the URL. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://yourdomain.com/textfile");
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: thanks for response , but i have not a website and domain, i just have a server with windows server

Comment: You can still use this approach by sending your request to an internal IP address on your local area network.

Comment: WebRequest is probably too low-level. I suggest using WebClient